# Reading xls file is returning html tags using library xlsx

Tags: node.js, typescript, xlsx

I am using xlsx library of nodejs for reading xls file. According to the document the library supports xls file format. On reading I am getting html tags along with it.
I can remove the html tags using regex or replace function but does the library give support to do that as I couldn't find it in the documentation?

Excel File format: Microsoft Excel 97-2003 Worksheet (.xls)

The demo link they have provided in their documentation https://oss.sheetjs.com/sheetjs/ works but when I try to do the same with my code it doesn't give the desired result.

```
let xlsx = require('xlsx');
let fs = require('fs');

let workBookData = xlsx.readFile('data.xls'); // parses a file
console.log(workBookData);
```

Here is an image of the result I am getting.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue/bug in the library. A PR has been created for this and it will be fixed in the new version of the library.